# Bad state in delete action with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to put together what I think is a pretty straightforward ember delete action (based on this example: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/migrating-from-ember-data-0-13-to-1-0-0-beta-1-my-findings/2368) from an Index Controller and I think I must be missing something.

```
actions: {
  deleteZone: function (zone) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the zone?")) {
      var _this = this;

      zone.deleteRecord();

      zone.save().then(
        function () {
          _this.transitionToRoute('zones.index');
        },
        function (error) {
          zone.rollback();
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I'm running into trouble when I try to delete a zone that has a corresponding dependency.  In this case, the server (Rails 4) throws an exception and returns the following JSON:

```
{"status":422,"message":"Cannot delete record because of dependent projects","errors":{}}
```

However, while I believe the server returns the correct error, the UI seems to fail before it gets that far.  If I put a debugger on the line after zone.rollback() inside the catch function I get this error:

```
Attempted to handle event `becameInvalid` on <App.Zone:ember1276:6> while in state root.deleted.inFlight. Called with {}.
```

I'm running on ember 1.4.0-beta.1, ember-data 1.0.0-beta.4 (ActiveModelAdapter) and rails 4.0.1.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Manually transitioning to a loaded.saved state after the rollback seems to resolve the issue:

```
zone.transitionTo('loaded.saved');
```

After upgrading to the latest ember/ember-data and slightly modifying the JSON response I'm now able to extract the error message out of the JSON using the error reference passed in to the catch expression.

```
{"status":422,"message":"translation missing: en.Invalid zone","errors":{"base":["Cannot delete record because dependent projects exist"]}}
```

And ember versions:

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0-beta.1+canary.4d69bca7 ember.js?body=1:3307
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.5+canary.2e773365 ember.js?body=1:3307
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.0.0 ember.js?body=1:3307
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into to this issue as well. Running `model.transitionTo('loaded.saved');` helped to vaoid any errors thrown, *but* the model is destroyed as well.

If one wants to keep the model in the store, one must *re-inject it*, which seems odd, but works:

```
var model = this.get('model');
var store = model.store;
model.deleteRecord();
model.save().catch(function(err){
    model.transitionTo('loaded.saved');
    var payload = model.serialize({includeId: true});
    store.unloadRecord(model)
    store.pushPayload('nestedSet',{nested_set:payload});
});
```

I am running:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.8.0-beta.1+canary.d6d4f01d
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.9
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

For version testing completeness same happens on `ember-data#1.0.0-beta.7`!

Hope it helps, if anyone runs into this too.